# Why does the F-16 canopy have a K-shaped 'latch'?

Tags: aircraft-design, f-16, canopy

Why is the F-16 canopy latch (the yellow painted part) shaped like a K? It's a very funky shape, and I'm wondering if that functions as more than just a latch. 
[image]

Comment: Are you asking about the yellow thing?  Doesn't look like a normal part of the aircraft, but rather something that's installed during some sort of maintenance or other operation to prevent certain things from being activated.  What's the source of that photo? The original source may have a caption that helps understand what's shown there.

Comment: I edited the question to clarify what I'm asking about, and it is a permanent part of the plane.

Comment: How do you know it's a permanent part of the plane? Do you think 'spider guard' refers to the yellow thing?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The function of the form is to act as a throttle stop when the part is in the position shown in the picture. It prevents full movement of the throttle when canopy is not securely closed and sealed.

When the canopy is closed, the latch is moved by pushing the bottom part of the latch towards the outside of the plane. This moves the throttle stop out of way and actuates the canopy seal.

See [this Youtube video](https://youtu.be/y12CarFhw8c) for an example, latch operated at 0:25.